# Filter print() calls ? on global or per module level?

Tags: python, debugging

I have in my utils.py the following functions which I use for debugging info ...

```
 say = print
 log = print
```

I want to declare them in such a way, so that I can switch them ON/OFF. If possible on per module basis.

F.e. let say I want to test something and enable/disable printing ...

I don't want to use logging, because it is too cumbersome and requires more typing..

I'm using this for quick debugging and eventually delete those prints

---

in utils.py

```
say = print
log = print

def nope(*args, **kwargs): return None
```

in blah.py

```
from utils import *
class ABC:
  def abc(self): say(111)
```

in ipython :

```
from blah import *
a = ABC()
a.abc()
111
say(222)
222

say = nope
a.abc(111)
111
say(222)
None
```

Comment: Sounds like you want to re-implement the [logging](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html) package.

Comment: logging is not well suited for quick and dirty debugging ...

Comment: If quick and dirty is your standard then you are absolutely right.

Comment: if u have a bug which is hard to debug and u need to print at different places ... setting up or using logging is non-starter .. on the other hand setting quick prints ... test .. fix and once done cleanup the prints is ideal for this case scenario

Comment: If you need to check values in many places you should use a debugger.

Comment: the last time I used debugger was Turbo Pascal ;) ... I'm not a debugger guy ;(  ... i suppose everyone has different style

Comment: It takes about 3 lines of code to set up logging, so I'm not sure how much easier you can make it: `from logging import basicConfig, info, INFO; basicConfig(level=INFO); info('Hello world! %s', 42)`

Answer (score 2):

You can always redefine say/log to do nothing later on.

```
Python 3.8.2 (default, Apr 27 2020, 15:53:34)
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> say = print
>>> say("hello")
hello
>>> def say(*args, **kwargs):
...  return None
...
>>> say("hello")
>>>
```

Comment: defined nope() fun.. then doing say = nope .. and has effect only when i say() in the ipython session

Comment: Either you're not setting it in the right place, or you're not setting it at the right time.  Remember that if you're setting something in a different module, you'll need to use its fully-qualified name.

Comment: To set it on a per-module basis, you can also change the name when importing; `from utils import nope as say`

Answer (score 0):

You could used `sys.stdout.write("\033[K")` to overwrite/clear the previous line at the terminal when you don't want it logged or like:

```
def removeLine(dontWant):
    if dontWant == True:
        sys.stdout.write("\033[K")
```

where dontWant is set within the module or class or as a glob even or whatever based on when you want it and then removeLine is call after every log event.

Comment: `== True` is unnecessary in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

At the end this is what I wrote :

https://github.com/vsraptor/quick-debug/blob/master/debug.py

Quick debugging : if you are like me and are not used to a debugger
or logging is too cumbersome, then this is for you.